# Android Espresso check selected spinner text

Tags: android, android-espresso

I have this code in my Espresso test

```
onView(withId(R.id.src))
    .perform(click());
onData(hasToString(startsWith("CCD")))
    .perform(click());
onView(withId(R.id.src))
    .check(matches(withText(containsString("CCD"))));
```

What I'm trying to do is to click the item in the `Spinner` and check if it's indeed selected in the `Spinner`.

**But I'm getting this error:**

> android.support.test.espresso.base.DefaultFailureHandler$AssertionFailedWithCauseError: 'with text: a string containing "CCD"' doesn't match the selected view.
>   Expected: with text: a string containing "CCD"
>   Got: "AppCompatSpinner{id=2131558533, res-name=src, visibility=VISIBLE, width=528, height=163, has-focus=false, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=true, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=true, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=1}"

Comment: In test spresso documentation they show a solution to select a item inside the spinner from its index position I think is the right way... URL : https://github.com/vgrec/EspressoExamples/blob/master/app/src/androidTest/java/com/vgrec/espressoexamples/SpinnerSelectionTest.java

Answer (score 83, accepted):

Replace `withText()` with `withSpinnerText()`

```
onView(withId(spinnerId)).perform(click());
onData(allOf(is(instanceOf(String.class)), is(selectionText))).perform(click());
onView(withId(spinnerId)).check(matches(withSpinnerText(containsString(selectionText))));
```

Reference: https://code.google.com/p/android-test-kit/issues/detail?id=85

Comment: what is the selectionText  here??

Comment: That's a string - the spinner text, the same one that is visible to user.

Comment: How do I just grab the Spinner object itself and have my way with it, without using these accessor methods? Or is that forbidden due to threads, or the other standard Android excuses?

Comment: This link unfortunately is broken. @Jonas any idea what the correct link supposed to be?

Comment: Can't find the correct link anymore. In the link there was an error report and fix for it. Generally just using matcher function withSpinnerText() should solve the issue these days and details in link were just additional historical info. Long time ago espresso did not have withSpinnerText().

Comment: Thank you so much, worked like a charm. I wasn't willing to go through clumsy Espresso API docs to find the solution. You saved my ton of time. I wish these APIs were bit straight forward to work with because on a surface level these  nested calls make zero sense.

Answer (score 14):

Really simple solution that worked out for me .....without using matcher for CustomSpinner

```
onView(withId(R.id.custom_spinner)).perform(click());
onData(anything()).atPosition(1).perform(click());
onView(withId(R.id.custom_spinner)).check(matches(withSpinnerText(containsString("yourstring"))));
```

Comment: This seems more straight-forward than the accepted answer.  What makes the accepted answer better than this? (especially since the accepted answer references a dead link)

Answer (score 4):

For custom adapter i had yo create a custom matcher:

```
 onView(withId(R.id.spinner)).perform(click());
 onData(allOf(is(instanceOf(YourCustomClass.class)), withMyValue("Open"))).perform(click());


public static <T> Matcher<T> withMyValue(final String name) {
    return new BaseMatcher<T>() {
        @Override
        public boolean matches(Object item) {
            return item.toString().equals(name);
        }

        @Override
        public void describeTo(Description description) {

        }
    };
}
```

Then you must override toString() method on your custom class.

Comment: YouCustomClass is the adapter class and item is an item from the adapter?

Comment: what is ```YourCustomClass```? is it like class model?

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

```
 private void selectSpinnerItem(final int resId, final String selection) {
    onView(withId(resId)).perform(click());
    onData(hasToString(selection)).perform(click());
    onView(withId(resId)).check(matches(withSpinnerText(containsString(selection))));
}
```