# Android. Espresso. How to click on Spinner item with text?

Tags: android, android-spinner, android-testing, android-espresso

I am trying to write a test that performs a click on a `Spinner` item by text.

My test contains these lines:

```
onView(withId(R.id.spn_trans_type))
    .perform(click());
onData(anything())
    .inAdapterView(withId(R.id.spn_trans_type))
    .onChildView(allOf(withId(textViewIdToTest), withText(expectedText)))
    .perform(click());
```

But I got an exception: `NoMatchingViewException: No views in hierarchy found matching: with id: com.rirdev.aalf.demo:id/spn_trans_type`

How to find spinner adapter view? In other words what should I put into `inAdapterView()` method ?

Answer (score 21):

I've already found this answer:

> Replace `withText()` with `withSpinnerText()`
>
> ```java
> onView(withId(spinnerId)).perform(click());
> onData(allOf(is(instanceOf(String.class)), is(selectionText))).perform(click());
> onView(withId(spinnerId)).check(matches(withSpinnerText(containsString(selectionText))));
> ```
>
> Reference:
>   https://code.google.com/p/android-test-kit/issues/detail?id=85
>
> From:
>   [Android Espresso check selected spinner text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31420839/android-espresso-check-selected-spinner-text)

So instead of using a bit complicated:

```java
onData(anything())
    .inAdapterView(withId(R.id.spn_trans_type))
    .onChildView(allOf(withId(textViewIdToTest), withText(expectedText)))
    .perform(click());
```

maybe you should use

```java
onData(allOf(is(instanceOf(String.class)), is(selectionText)))
    .perform(click());
onView(withId(spinnerId))
    .check(matches(withSpinnerText(containsString(selectionText))));
```

where `selectionText` would be your expected string value and `spinnerId` an id of your `Spinner` view.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, the simplest possible solution worked (Kotlin):

```
onView(withId(R.id.spinner)).perform(click())
onView(withText("Spinner Item 1")).perform(click());
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use this code:

```
ViewInteraction customTextView = onView(
                  allOf(withId(R.id.tv_spinner_desc), withText("hello"), isDisplayed()));
customTextView.perform(click());
```