# select a spinner element with uiautomator

Tags: android, ui-automation, android-uiautomator

I've tried multiple options. Neither worked for me. Is it possible to select an element of a spinner using uiautomator?

Code example:

```
UiObject spinner = mDevice.findObject(new UiSelector().className("android.widget.Spinner")
            .instance(0));

        try {
             Integer cnt = spinner.getChildCount();
             if (cnt > 0) {
                 UiObject item = spinner.getChild(new UiSelector().index(cnt-1));
                 item.click();
             }
        } catch (UiObjectNotFoundException e){}
```

Comment: Instead of using the UI automation, you need to use the espresso library: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31420839/android-espresso-check-selected-spinner-text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This snippet will select an item from the Spinner

```
    (new UiScrollable(new UiSelector().resourceId("com.dtmilano.android.demoapplication:id/spinner").index(1).packageName("com.dtmilano.android.demoapplication"))).click();
    List<UiObject2> children = mDevice.findObjects(By.res("android:id/text1").pkg("com.dtmilano.android.demoapplication"));
    for (UiObject2 uio2 : children) {
        if ("New Zealand".equals(uio2.getText())) {
            uio2.click();
            break;
        }
    }
```

it's using a sample Activity with a Spinner showing countries

[image]

The first part was automatically generated by [Enumerate Children](https://github.com/dtmilano/CulebraTester-public/wiki/Features#enumerate-children) feature of [CulebraTester](http://culebra.dtmilano.com/).

Comment: thank Diego, do you know by chance what happens if UIObject2 doesn't exist? Unlike UIObject, that doesn't has `exist()` method

Comment: Throws an exception

Answer (score 2):

One can select `By.res`, but without parameter `packageName` (which is `android`):

```
UiObject2 spinner = mDevice.findObject(By.res(packageName, "spinner"));
spinner.click();
sleep(2000);

List<UiObject2> items = mDevice.findObjects(By.res("android:id/text1"));
items.get(1).click(500);
```