# Why does recorded espresso test code for selecting a Spinner drop-down item result in different, incompatible code on different Android versions?

Tags: android, android-espresso

Starting with recording an espresso test on an Android 9 device, I got a snippet of code for selecting an item in a Spinner drop-down like this:

```
ViewInteraction spinner = onView(
    allOf(withId(R.id.ModeDropDown),
        childAtPosition(
            allOf(withId(R.id.activity_setup_controls),
                childAtPosition(
                    withId(R.id.activity_setup_layout),
                        0)),
                    2)));
spinner.perform(scrollTo(), click());

DataInteraction checkedTextView = onData(anything())
    .inAdapterView(childAtPosition(
        withClassName(is("android.widget.PopupWindow$PopupBackgroundView")),
            0))
    .atPosition(mode); // drop-down position "mode"
checkedTextView.perform(click());
```

This code ran fine on Android 9, but when I took it to an Android 5 device it started giving me a failure at invocation of **checkedTextView.perform(click());** of:

"androidx.test.espresso.NoMatchingViewException: No views in hierarchy found matching: Child at position 0 in parent view.getClass().getName() matches: is "android.widget.PopupWindow$PopupBackgroundView"
If the target view is not part of the view hierarchy, you may need to use Espresso.onData to load it from one of the following AdapterViews:android.widget.ListPopupWindow$DropDownListView{32dcb2b9 VFED.VC. .F...... 24,24-887,606}".

So I re-recorded the test on an Android 5 device and the DataInteraction changed to this:

```
DataInteraction checkedTextView = onData(anything())
    .inAdapterView(withClassName(is("android.widget.ListPopupWindow$DropDownListView")))
    .atPosition(mode); // drop-down position "mode"
```

Note that the error suggestion is reflected in what the espresso recorder generated on the Android 5 device.  However, this second batch of code runs fine on Android 5, but gives the following error on an Android 9 device:

"androidx.test.espresso.NoMatchingViewException: No views in hierarchy found matching: view.getClass().getName() matches: is "android.widget.ListPopupWindow$DropDownListView"
If the target view is not part of the view hierarchy, you may need to use Espresso.onData to load it from one of the following AdapterViews:android.widget.DropDownListView{1172231 VFED.VC.. .F...... 16,16-592,406}".

And in case it matters, the activity layout XML implements a drop-down Spinner inside a RelativeLayout wrapped in a ScrollView that looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:id="@+id/activity_setup_layout"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:gravity="left"
   android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
   android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
   android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
   android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
   android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
   android:layout_centerInParent="true"
   android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
   android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
   android:background="@drawable/maingadget3x"
   android:fillViewport="true"
   android:scrollbars="none"
   tools:context="com.mycompany.myapp.SetupActivity">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/activity_setup_controls"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <View
            android:id="@+id/separator1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="5dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/ModeSetupHeading"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/separator1"
            android:layout_margin="5sp"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:maxLines="2"
            android:singleLine="false"
            android:text="@string/SetupModeProfileHeadingString"
            android:textSize="28sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/ModeDropDown"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/ModeSetupHeading"
            android:background="@android:drawable/btn_dropdown"
            android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
            tools:ignore="DuplicateSpeakableTextCheck" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Am I stuck with dealing with OS version-dependent test code, or is there a solution to this problem that I'm not seeing?

Comment: On Android 12 my generated test don't even compile with PopupBackgroundView marked as 'Unresolved reference'.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit dismayed nobody was willing to engage this question, but I came across a solution to a similar question @ [Android Espresso check selected spinner text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31420839/android-espresso-check-selected-spinner-text) that suited me:

```
DataInteraction checkedTextView = onData(anything()).atPosition(mode);
checkedTextView.perform(click());
```

I also threw in a check to make sure the operation was successful:

```
String modeString = getResourceString(modeStringIndex);        
onView(withId(R.id.ModeDropDown))
    .check(matches(withSpinnerText(containsString(modeString))));
```

This wasn't the accepted answer from that post, but since the accepted answer included dead reference links, I felt compelled not to use an answer that I didn't fully understand.  I hope someone else finds this useful.